# Why does the `System.Nullable<T>` type has the `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)` attribute?

Tags: c#, clr, nullable, custom-attributes

Why does the `System.Nullable<T>` type has the `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)` attribute?

I found the following piece of text and code in the **CLR via C#** book:

> Here is the logical representation of how the System.Nullable type
>   is defined:

```
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct { 
   //... unrelated to the question code
}
```

So, why is it logical for the `System.Nullable<T>` to have the `StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)` attribute being applied? I believe that it would be enough to answer my question if someone would just explain for what case (or cases) was the attribute added (i.e. what purpose does it serve).

I understand what the attribute does. I do not understand why is it necessary to have the attribute for the `System.Nullable<T>` type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't actually have that attribute. If it used to when the book was written, it doesn't anymore.

You can see this for yourself for .NET Framework (source [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/17b97365645da62cf8a49444d979f94a59bbb155/mscorlib/system/nullable.cs#L25-L27)):

```cs
    [Serializable]
    [System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable] // This only applies to field layout
    public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
    {
```

and for .NET Core (source [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/98d47d5fc0f1b232869a9abd27729235fd7355b0/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Nullable.cs#L14-L17)):

```cs
    [Serializable]
    [NonVersionable] // This only applies to field layout
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TypeForwardedFrom("mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")]
    public partial struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
    {
```